# How to disable plugin when unable to log in?

Tags: plugins

I'm getting a blank page for both the front end and the CP/admin, and am tyring to figure out why. I changed my hard drive at about the same time as making a bunch of changes to a plugin, so just trying to figure out what I've screwed up.

I already did this: deleted `vendor/craftcms` followed by

```
composer clearcache
composer install
```

Is there a way to disable plugins from outside the CP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable plugins by adding their handles to an array [`disabledPlugins`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#disabledplugins) in your `config/general.php` file:

```php
<?php
    '*' => [
        'isSystemLive' => true,
        'disabledPlugins' => [
            'redactor',
            'some-plugin',
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ],
```

Comment: Thank you, Mats.  That doesn't seem to have solved my main problem, but it helps to rule things out!  Index.php doesn't seem to get past ```require_once CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/autoload.php';```

Comment: Finally, it was a permissions problem accessing the autoload.php.